# Get results of multdimensional array from form post

Tags: php, forms

So I have a form which is build up like:

```
<input name="website['menu']['id']" type="number" value="1">
<input type="text" value="#000000" name="website['color']['primary']['hex']">
```

Now i want to read out those values in php after they are submit.
I tried the following code, but when I var_dump it it gives me null.

```
if (isset($_POST['website'])) {

    $result = $_POST['website'];

    var_dump($result['menu']['id']);exit;
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Remove the **quote** from field name

```
<input name="website[menu][id]" type="number" value="1">
<input type="text" value="#000000" name="website[color][primary][hex]">
```

And access the variable in php like:

```
echo $_POST['website']['menu']['id'];
```

Answer (score 0):

```
Try this,

<?php
print_r($_POST['website']);
print_r($_POST['website']['menu']['id']);
?>
<form action="" method="POST"/>
<input name="website[menu][id]" type="number" value="1">
<input type="text" value="#000000" name="website['color']['primary']['hex']">
<input type="submit" value="submit"/>
</form>
```